# ReportViewer cannot find data source remotely

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

this is the first time I have tried this so I am probably missing something that is staring me right in the face.

I have an ASP.NET page where the user fills in a request which then emails a PDF rendered from a ReportViewer instance.

It all works fine when I run it locally through the ASP.NET localhost but when I try and run it of the webserver it fails with the following message:

An error has occurred during report processing.
Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'.

I can preview the report via the web based report manager via http://servername/reports which works without any problem and using the report editor in VS2005.

I suspect it is something to do with the credentials but I am at a loss.  The data source is set with a username and password but this is saved within the datasource.

I have been looking at this for about a day now with no joy.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woohoo...I managed to fix the problem.

It was the credentials after all.  Even though I was specifying a username and password it was still using the webserver default credentials.  I got a new user setup and it worked a treat.

As the error message didnt mention anything to do with unauthorised access and being able to pull the data through using VS2005 and the web browser for viewing the reports I thought it was the way I was referencing the report.

Thanks to those who had started to ponder about this.